# Python package publish by myself cannot be installed

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi, setup.py

I'm new for publishing package on pypi. I tried to publish my package but I cannot install it even by myself. Would u help me take a look for where I'm wrong?

ERORR:

```bash
# by pip
pip install fastapi-casdoor 

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement fastapi-casdoor (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for fastapi-casdoor


# by poetry
poetry add fastapi-casdoor

Could not find a matching version of package fastapi-casdoor
```

setup.py

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# encoding: utf-8

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup()
```

setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
name = fastapi-casdoor
author = Winrey
author_email = i@iaside.com
version = 0.1.8
description = Integration Casdoor with FastAPI
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = https://github.com/winrey/python-fastapi-casdoor
license_files = LICENSE
keywords = auth, casdoor, fastapi, dependency
classifiers = 
    Development Status :: 3 - Alpha
    License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License
    Programming Language :: Python
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3.11
    Framework :: FastAPI
    Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP
    Natural Language :: English
    Natural Language :: Chinese (Simplified)
    

[options]
package_dir=
    = src
packages=find:
python_requires = >=3.6
install_requires =
    fastapi
    python-dateutil
    PyJWT
    pydantic

[options.packages.find]
where=src
```

project: https://github.com/winrey/python-fastapi-casdoor/
pypi: https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-casdoor/

```bash
# but it can be searched on poetry
poetry search fastapi-casdoor

fastapi-casdoor (0.1.8)
 Integration Casdoor with FastAPI

casdoor (1.8.0)
 Python SDK built for Casdoor
```

I try to modify the `python_requires = >3.10` to `python_requires = >=3.10` and to `python_requires = >=3.6` and finally try to delete it, but not worked.

Comment: https://pypi.org/project/fastapi-casdoor/0.1.8/#files You publish egg files. `pip` cannot install eggs. Publish source dists and wheels.

Comment: @phd thanks a lot! I used to upload npm package and It's my first time upload python package and It trapped me for days, I tried a lot and even publish from 0.1.0 to 0.1.8 to try to solve this. You really save me from it, Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Here are two Distributions for a python package: Source Distributions and Built Distributions.

And there are two types of Built Distributions: Egg and Wheel.

If you want your package installed by pip/poetry, you need to upload Wheel package or Source Distributions.

You can build and upload them by following commend:

```bash
# update your python build if needs
python3 -m pip install --upgrade build

# build package
python3 -m build

# upload to pypi
twine upload dist/*
```

If you are interested in the different between egg or wheel, you can go to the following link:
https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/discussions/wheel-vs-egg/

If not, just choose wheel :)

Here are some main advantages:

> Wheels are the new standard of Python distribution and are intended to
> replace eggs. Support is offered in pip >= 1.4 and setuptools >= 0.8.
>
> - Advantages of wheels Faster installation for pure Python and native C
>   extension packages.
> - Avoids arbitrary code execution for installation. (Avoids setup.py)
> - Installation of a C extension does not require a compiler on Linux, Windows or macOS.
> - Allows better caching for testing and continuous integration.
> - Creates .pyc files as part of installation to ensure they match the Python interpreter used.
> - More consistent installs across platforms and machines.

I'm sorry for this basic question, but if you are a python package starter like me, hope it can help you～

And it's all @phd remind me and let me notice that, thanks.

If there are something I misunderstanding, welcome to correct me :)